# Radon transform for image watermarking in Matlab

Tags: matlab, watermark, matrix-transform

I want to do digital image watermarking with Radon Transform in Matlab. But I am facing some problem at the beginning. Suppose I take a matrix and then I perform Radon and Inverse Radon transform on it like this:

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3];
theta = 0:180;
R = radon(A,theta);
B = iradon(R,theta)
```

The matrix B here is quite different from original matrix A.

Also if I want to embed a watermark in a specific position of the transformed matrix, In the extraction process I can't get the watermark in that position.

I need any kind of help about how can I embed and extract watermark using Radon transform.